# ThreeJS Softer/Gradient Shadow Casting With Alpha Texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

Using ThreeJS I've made a setup that displays a model with a complex material. I'm using an alpha texture to make semi-transparent surfaces, like glass. However when shadows are being cast, the shadow is removed completely instead of using the alpha texture as gradient.

Basically I want a similar effect like this BabylonJS example: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#P1RZV0

When casting shadows I'm using the `MeshDepthMaterial` in order to let the light cast shadows through transparent surfaces, like this:

```
var customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial( {
    depthPacking: THREE.RGBADepthPacking,
    alphaMap: alphaTex,
    alphaTest: 1,
    skinning: true
})
```

This works fine however as mentioned, shadows should not disappear completely but rather use the alpha texture as indicator how strong the shadow should be. The more opaque a surface is the stronger the shadow should be and vice versa.

You can take a look at the project here: https://jsfiddle.net/miger/2c7no6mj/

Apparently BabylonJS makes it as simple as using the parameter `.transparencyShadow = true;` and I've not found anything simmilar in ThreeJS. It seems that there has not been an official solution implemented in ThreeJS yet. Instead the only thing I found was this discussion about it here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10600

I've already implemented some GLSL code in order to get selective bloom working. I'm guessing to implement the shadow effect I'm looking for I need to do something with the shaders but I do not know how.

These are the shaders I'm using so far:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
uniform sampler2D baseTexture;
uniform sampler2D bloomTexture;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = ( texture2D( baseTexture, vUv ) + vec4( 1.0 ) * texture2D( bloomTexture, vUv ) );
}
</script>
```

And this is how the selective bloom is implemented using `.onBeforeCompile`:

```
child.material.onBeforeCompile = shader => {
    shader.uniforms.globalBloom = uniforms.globalBloom;
    shader.fragmentShader = `
        uniform float globalBloom;
      ${shader.fragmentShader}
    `.replace(
        `#include <dithering_fragment>`,
      `#include <dithering_fragment>
        if (globalBloom > 0.5){
            gl_FragColor = texture2D( emissiveMap, vUv );
        }
      `
    );
}
```

I'm really bad with shaders, there have been some solutions in the above mentioned discussion, however I've just way to little experience with shaders and GLSL to know what I need to do.

How can I implement soft/gradient shadow casting using an alpha texture as strength indicator?

Comment: Looks like [that pull-request](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15999) has been kicked down the road several times, and it's still not part of the core. I was going to suggest digging through the code to implement yourself, but if you're not very well-versed with shaders, then maybe a baked-in [lightmap texture](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_lightmap) might be the only solution, if your meshes are static.

Comment: Meshes are not necessarily going to be static, baking the lightmap isn't going to cut it. I've already looked into the code but its just beyond me at the moment. It'll take some time until I get around it and actually find the time to deal with that myself. Hopefully someone else who knows this stuff better than me will come along and save the day..